# Validation throwing a 500

Tags: asp.net, validation

My validation isn't working.  I have two text boxes that someone can use to add "reviews".  The first required is for when if you try to add a review but do not give your name then the message "You didn't type your name!"  Should pop up.

```
public class Review
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You didn't type your name!")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You didn't type anything!")]
    [MaxLength( 200, ErrorMessage = "Review is too long.")]
    public string Reviews { get; set; }  
}
```

Here is the code for the view:

```
<div class="container">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="review in controller.reviews">
    {{review.name}} <br />
    {{review.reviews}}
    <span ng-show="account.getClaim('IsAdmin') || account.isLoggedIn()">
    <a href="/editReview/{{review.id}}">Edit</a>
        </span>
    <span ng-show="account.getClaim('IsAdmin') || account.isLoggedIn()">
    <a ng-click="controller.delete(review.id)">Delete</a>
        </span>
</li>
</ul>

<form ng-submit="controller.save()">
<div>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="controller.newReview.name" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Review:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="controller.newReview.reviews" /> 
</div>
<span ng-show="account.getClaim('IsAdmin') || account.isLoggedIn()">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
    </span>
</form>
</div>
```

And finally here's the code i'm using in the API controller:

```
[Authorize]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Review review)
    {
        var user = this.User as ClaimsPrincipal;

        if(!user.HasClaim("IsAdmin", "true"))
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(this.ModelState);
        }

        _repo.SaveReview(review);

        return Created("/reviews/" + review.Id, review);
    }
```

When I run the code and I try create a review with a name and body it creates the review just fine.  However, if I try to do so without a name a 500 error pops up in the console.

Any advice will be very helpful!